# Generating SCOM alerts for web servers

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, monitoring, monitor, scom

I have 4-7 sharepoint servers. We have a scom alert already implemented to generate alert if the server is down. But we want to implement scom alert if the website is down.

Can we genearate alert using scom by using ping functionality? 
My idea is, we ping the server continuosly and when the website is unresponsive for some time we get alert saying that the website is unresposive.

Can this be implemented? And how much effort is needed? And do we need any other services to be implemented?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ravi,

Forgive me for the post being more philosophy and less answer.

For better or worse, Microsoft has resisted implemented a simple ping monitor in SCOM. Their is a solid reason for this. It would be overly leveraged by folks that don't know any better. The result of which would reflect poorly on the quality of SCOM as a monitoring tool. What I mean by that is that a ping monitor is a terrible idea as it doesn't tell the poor soul that was awoken at 2am much of anything beyond the highest level notion that *something* is wrong.

If you have 5 minutes to sit in front of the SCOM console to create a ping alert then you would serve your support teams much better if you spent those same 5 minutes creating a Web Application Availability monitor. The reason for this is that the Web App Avail monitor will actually look at the response to ensure that it is logical and successful.

Here is the documentation to create a Web Application Availability Monitor. It looks difficult only until your first implementation. It really is a snap. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881882(v=sc.12).aspx

Consider that if you had a ping monitor and someone accidentally deleted your index.html file, your ping will happily chug along without telling anyone. Same with a bad code update. Heck, you could even stop your web application server and ping is still going to respond.

Conversely, If you had a Web App Avail monitor pointed at each of the nodes in a load balanced web farm and your load balancer failed, all of your Web monitors will continue to post as healthy while your monitor looking at the load balancer will start to fail. A quick glace at the console will tell your support team that indeed the issue is not with the web servers themselves.

It is a good philosophy to implement your monitors in a way that they testing the target as completely as possible and in the most isolated way possible. You would not want to point a Web App Avail monitor at a load balancer as you would not necessarily know which endpoint did not respond to SCOM to trigger the alert. Some folks go to great lengths to work around this by implementing health check pages that respond with there hostnames. This is usually not necessary, simply create a monitor against each individual node. You are going to want to monitor your load balancer directly so that you know it is up as well.

On another note, there already is a SharePoint management pack (actually one for each version of SharePoint) that you can download from MS for free. This management pack will automatically discovery and monitor all of the components of SharePoint in your infrastructure. It works quite well but if you are new to SCOM then the volume of data and alerts that it creates can be a bit overwhelming at first.

SharePoint 2016 (there is one for each version) management pack: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2015/09/08/system-center-operations-management-pack-for-sharepoint-server-2016-it-preview/

There is also a third party management pack that allows you to simply create ping monitors. People REALLY want this. I respectfully will tell you that that they are doing more harm then good in the majority of implementations that use this. But at the end of the day sometimes you just want something that works and you understand so here it is:

Ping management pack: https://www.opslogix.com/ping-management-pack/